# Имитация сенсора приближения

Tags: ios, xcode

Есть ли возможность смоделировать использование сенсора приближения с помощью симулятора iOS в Xcode?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В симуляторе iOS такой возможности нет

Comment: Жалко( Спасибо!